# Creating table with variable name php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, variables, create-table

I'am trying to create table with variable name and columns via forms here's my query

```
$execute =  mysql_query('CREATE TABLE '.$tName.'(
            '.$cName.' '.$cType.' )');
```

And it's creating table with name from variable `$tName` but it doesnt create the columns.

Comment: Are you repeating this same query for adding columns? Once the table is created you need to `ALTER` it to add columns.

Comment: No, it's just a sample, i know that i can modify it, but i have to create table with theese columns.

Comment: Turn on error reporting or check your logs and see if you are getting any errors returned. From reading this one line I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Perhaps `$cName` and `$cType` are undefined at this point.

Comment: @ToothlessRebel checked theese variables has their values and there is no any error, it just creating table without column

Comment: What is the value of `$execute` after this? It should be `true` or `false` for this type of query. If `false` then there was a MySQL issue, if `true` I am well and truly stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql= "CREATE TABLE $tName($cName $cType(45),$cName $cType(50))";

//echo $sql;
$op =mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK try this, I think it gives the general idea

```
<?php
include 'connect-db.php';
$tbl_name='kerry';
$field1='name';
$field2='value';
$field3='date';
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `{$tbl_name}`
(
$field1 varchar(15),
$field2 int,
$field3 date
)");
?>
```

Comment: Out of interest why was this question downvoted - it seems clear and useful